# redirect error and recursive login screen/auth screen problems with facebooker iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebooker

i am using the facebooker gem from http://github.com/mmangino/facebooker for developing a rails 2 facebook application (iframe). i am wondering if this is a bug from facebooker:

when i am using

```
ensure_application_is_installed_by_facebook_user
```

in the application controller, the iframe gets rendered in an infinite loop. i found out that in vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/facebooker/rails/controller.rb line 63 the request_is_facebook_iframe? is never entered for my iframe app. it seems that params["fb_sig_in_iframe"] is always not set.

is this a facebooker problem or did i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

don't know if you got an answer but to avoid the infinite frame loop you should use

```
  ensure_authenticated_to_facebook
```

instead of

```
ensure_application_is_installed_by_facebook_user
```

There is a good tutorial on setting up a iframe facebook app here:

[Creating a Facebook (iFrame) app using Ruby on Rails & Facebooker](http://www.cowboycoded.com/2009/10/14/creating-a-facebook-iframe-app-using-ruby-on-rails-facebooker/)

Hope that helps!